# ImportError: No module named dtmilano

Tags: android, eclipse, pydev, jython, androidviewclient

Hi I am new to python development. I am trying to execute the code given at http://dtmilano.blogspot.in/2012/02/monkeyrunner-interacting-with-views.html but when ever i am trying to execute the code i get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gur31265\workspace\MonkeyRunnerForSmartRecorder\com\test\Runner.py", line 23, in <module>
    from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
ImportError: No module named dtmilano
```

I am using eclipse with PyDev and Jython 2.5.3. I had also configured Python 32 on eclipse running on Windows 7 machine. Other Python scripts are running fine but i don't know why code given on dtmilano's blog is causing this error. I had also installed AndroidViewClient and set the ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME in system path. Please help.

Comment: What's the `sys.path` you get?

Comment: C:\\Users\\gur31265\\workspace\\MonkeyRunnerForSmartRecorder\\com\\test, C:\\Users\\gur31265\\workspace\\MonkeyRunnerForSmartRecorder, D:\\E & F Drive Back up\\Program Files\\Android\\android-sdk\\tools\\lib\\monkeyrunner.jar, C:\\Users\\gur31265\\Downloads\\dtmilano-AndroidViewClient-bd98f63\\AndroidViewClient\\src, D:\\E & F Drive Back up\\Program Files\\Android\\android-sdk\\tools\\lib\\jython.jar, C:\\Program Files\\Python32\\DLLs, C:\\Program Files\\Python32\\lib, C:\\Program Files\\Python32, C:\\Program Files\\Python32\\lib\\site-packages, C:\\Windows\\system32\\python32.zip

Comment: If i run it as python module i get the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gur31265\workspace\MonkeyRunner\com\htc\monkey\runner\MonkeyRunner.py", line 19, in <module>
    from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient 
ImportError: No module named dtmilano.android.viewclient

Comment: jars? You're using jython? The script you link to uses `monkeyrunner` as executable, not Python...

Comment: I am working on windows 7 and i don't have monkeyrunner.exe if i try to set it as interpreter it eclipse will not accept it. Yes, to do this i need a Linux machine.

Comment: Now i had switched onto Ubuntu. I did tried to set monkeyrunner as python interpreter but eclipse is giving some errors. Can you help me out with this how to set monkeyrunner as python interpreter.

Comment: I would start by googling `monkeyrunner` and read the doc.

Comment: @Pierre GM thanks for your support, I managed to make things work but eclipse intigration is still few miles away but i'll reach there soon. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a detailed explanation about how to use `PYTHONPATH` and `ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME` environment variables from Eclipse and PyDev and also from command line at http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2012/09/monkeyrunner-importing-from-pythonpath.html.

Briefly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env monkeyrunner
import re
import sys
import os
import java

# This must be imported before MonkeyRunner and MonkeyDevice,
# otherwise the import fails.
# PyDev sets PYTHONPATH, use it
try:
    for p in os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(':'):
       if not p in sys.path:
          sys.path.append(p)
except:
    pass

try:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, View
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
```

Answer (score 1):

This took me a bit to work out. Make sure that you append the AndroidViewClient source directory to your path before you import MonkeyRunner.

The following will fail with `ImportError: No module named dtmilano`:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
sys.path.append('/path/to/android_view_client_home/src')
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
```

However, it will work if you just switch the order:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/android_view_client_home/src')
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
```

It seems that once it imports the `com` package for MonkeyRunner, it will only look in that package for `dtmilano`. However, if both `com` packages are in the path before you import anything, it will know to look in both locations.

Comment: This is IT! I've struggled so long! This is the only thing that made it work! Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to run an Monkey runner script test..after doing above i started to get "You should use a 'python' interpreter, not 'monkeyrunner' for this module" ...any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use monkeyrunner located in android SDK to run your code. For example:
to compile a file named help.py use following command:
c:>monkeyrunner help.py
same command will work on linux environment also.